# Clickable image to upload, when click FileUpload with Javascript not working correctly

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to implement a clickable image which will prompt image upload, user upload image, then display the image. So I used an `ImageButton` which will call a invisible `FileUpload`(currently visible) for image upload. However, `onchange()` doesn't seem to work, when I check, it seems to be the image is not uploaded to the `FileUpload` control.

So I tried debugging by making the `FileUpload` visible and click on the control directly click on the `FileUpload` control and select a photo, the image name is shown in the control. But when I use Javascript to click on `FileUpload` when `ImageButton` is clicked, and upload an image, the image name is not shown in the control, it remains 'No file chosen', meaning the image is not uploaded. Why is that?

Javascript code written on top of the page:

```
    function chooseFile() {
        $("#FileUpload1").click();
    }
    function fileChanged() {
        //do something
    }
```

ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" onchange="fileChanged()"/>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="chooseFile()" ImageUrl="images/placeholder.png" />
```

**EDIT 1**

Tried using `ClientIdMode='static'`

ASPX Code:

```
        function chooseFile() {
            $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").click());
        }
```

Generated Code:

```
        function chooseFile() {
            $("#FileUpload1").click());
        }
```

Control code:

```
    <input type="file" name="FileUpload1" id="FileUpload1" onchange="fileChanged()" />
    <input type="image" name="ImageButton1" id="ImageButton1" src="images/placeholder.png" onclick="chooseFile();" />
```

Comment: maybe ImageButton1.click? You are trying to click the fileupload....

Comment: @VDWWD yeah, i'm trying to click the FileUpload in code when ImageButton is clicked by user

Comment: a fileupload does not have a click event. A button does. You need to simulate what a user does.

Comment: @VDWWD Then is there a way to click the 'Choose File' in the FileUpload when I click on the ImageButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I realize that the file is empty because there is a postback happened right after the `ImageButton` is clicked, so even though it triggers the Javascript to click on the `FileUpload` and pops up file explorer for file selection, the connection between the file explorer and `FileUpload` is broken because of the postback.

To avoid postback when `ImageButton` is clicked, I programmatically set `OnClick` attribute of the `ImageButton` in Page_Load() like this, it calls the `chooseFile()` Javascript function, and return a false which stops the program from having a postback. Once it the `FileUpload` detects a file has been uploaded by using `onchange`, it calls `fileChanged()` which replaces the image inside `ImageButton`

```
ImageButton1.Attributes("OnClick") = "chooseFile();return false;"
```

.aspx Code:

```
function chooseFile() {
    document.getElementById("FileUpload1").click();
}

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" onchange="fileChanged()"/>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="chooseFile()" ImageUrl="images/placeholder.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

using ClientIDMode static as below to keep same id when render server side control

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" ClientIDMode="static" runat="server"/>
```

or acccess control in javascript using below

```
 function chooseFile() {
        $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").click();
    }
```

Comment: problem still remains

Comment: can you send generated html to validate

Comment: no problem, i've included the code in the post above

Comment: This code must be html not aspnet control for example   <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onchange="fileChanged()"/> should be <input type="file"  ID="FileUpload1" onchange="fileChanged()"/>

Comment: owh sorry, the control code i pasted was from my own code, not generated code, i'll change it

Comment: I've updated the code, can u check?

Comment: I tried many browser it works, what is jquery you used, what browser test on, is there any error appear in browser console

Comment: Your code which clicks the `FileUpload` control does work, however, a postback occured which causes the file explorer pop out to select image is disconnected from the `FileUpload`, so even if I have selected an image, the `FileUpload` is empty.

Comment: To prevent postback replace onclick by this chooseFile();return false;

Comment: Ah yess, I've already solve it just now by using the same code you've mentioned which I have found somewhere else. Thank you very much